# What do I need to install to have numpy do matix multiplication on multiple threads?

Tags: python, numpy, blas, openblas

Here are things that might be relevant though I'm not sure how exactly.

Not sure how to interpret the `ldd` outputs but people keep referencing them in answers so here they are:

```
ldd /usr/lib/libopenblas.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe23fe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcded57f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcded361000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcdecf9a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcdef0e2000)

ldd /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffcc83000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f41e4336000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f41e4118000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f41e3d51000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f41e5e99000)
```

Also, here are the runs on the `libblas.so` I know I shouldn't have ATLAS but no idea what I need to do for multithreading

```
update-alternatives --config libblas.so
There are 3 choices for the alternative libblas.so (providing /usr/lib/libblas.so).

  Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so    35        manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so             10        manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so   40        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I'm looking for a simple solution.

The reason I believe I don't have multithreading support is because in `top` it never goes above 100%.

Comment: Do you see other programs go above 100%? Does the total usage of all programs combined go over 100%?

Comment: I'm not running other programs. Not sure what you mean

Comment: It's unclear whether a program maxing out all cores on your machine would actually display a CPU usage over 100%. `top` isn't always configured to work like that.

Comment: so what should I do to check if it works?

Comment: also, given what I've shown do you think I should be able to run multithreaded matrix multiplications?

Comment: Dunno, on both counts.

Comment: A library such as numpy would certainly have multiple core support for matrix multiplication built in.

Comment: How do I check that it's working? Because I thought it was much more complicated to set up from googling around. It all depended on the BLAS libraries I use/configure